# mPDF: how to make $mpdf->writehtml() inline

Tags: php, mpdf

i tried to put looped photos in my mpdf but it doesn't display as inline.

heres my code:

```
while ($photos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_photo)) {
    $photo = $photos['photo'];
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<img src="/cert/uploads/patients/'.$photo.'" style="border: .5mm solid; width:45%; height:5.5cm;">');
};
```

This is what i get[image]

does anyone know how to make it as inline?.
i already tried putting `float:left` in the image but it only merges all the image and displays like in layer.

Answer (score 2):

try adding the image inside a table like:

```
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_cont);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<table>");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<tr>");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<td style='text-align:center;'>");
    while ($photos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_photo)) {
    $photo = $photos['photo'];

    /*$mpdf->Image('/cert/uploads/patients/'.$photo.'',10,0,45,45,'jpg','',true);*/

    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<img src="/cert/uploads/patients/'.$photo.'" style="margin: .5m; border: 1.5mm solid; width:45%; height:5.5cm;">');

    };
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("</td>");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("</tr>");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("</table>");
```